# how to initialize char *** from string liertal

Tags: c

But I am wondering how to initialize char *** in c.
initialize char* :

```
char *test = "hello";
printf("tets[0]=%s\n",test);
```

The following is initialize char **.

```
char **test = (char *[]) {"hello", "world"};
   printf("tets[1]=%s\n",test[1]);
```

So far I tried to initialize char ***:

```
// char ***test = (*(char *[])) {{"hello"}, {"world"}};
//char ***test = ((char **)[]) {{"hello"}, {"world"}};
```

Intended to achieve, initialize a char*** using text string literal.
Then i can use `printf("tets[1]=%s\n",(*test)[1])` to print out `world`.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. The question as is does not make sense.

Comment: How do I initialize a clay pot from a teabag? many ways: I could fill the pot full of teabags, and write "teabags" on it, or I could fill it with hot water and put a teabag in, or I could do that and steep the tea and take it back out, or I could cut open the teabags and pour the contents into the pot - all depending on what I want the result to be. Your question is like that. Do you want a pointer that points at a pointer that points at a pointer that points at a string?

Comment: @user253751 I update the correct question. Hope it will get clear. basically  from string literal is possible to construct a char ***.

Comment: @jian is it possible to initialize a clay pot from a teabag?

Comment: Do you want `test[0]` to be a pointer to an array of elements of type `char *` or should it point to a single `char *`?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel pointer to` char *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to additionally create a compound literal which is simply an object of type `char**` which points to the first element of the array you defined in the question, and make the `char ***` point to this `char **` object:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char ***test = &(char**){ (char *[]){"hello", "world" } };

    printf( "test[1]=%s\n", (*test)[1] );
}
```

This program has the desired output `world`.

However, adding this additional layer of indirection does not make much sense. It would make more sense to simply use a `char**` instead of a `char***`, as you did in the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can have compound literal containing compound literals.

```
char *test = "hello";
printf("tets[0]=%s\n",test);

char **test1 = (char *[]) {"hello", "world"};
   printf("tets[1]=%s\n",test1[1]);

char ***test2 = (char **[]){(char *[]) {"hello", "world"}, (char *[]) {"something", "else"}};
   printf("tets[1]=%s\n",test2[1][1]);

char **elem1 = (char *[]) {"hello", "world"};
char **elem2 = (char *[]) {"something", "else"};

char ***test3 = (char **[]){elem1, elem2};
   printf("tets[1]=%s\n",test2[1][0]);

/* --- or **** */

char ****test4 = (char ***[]){ (char **[]){(char *[]) {"hello", "world"}, (char *[]) {"something", "else"}}, 
                              (char **[]){(char *[]) {"four", "pointer"}, (char *[]) {"programmer", "king"}}};
   printf("tets[1]=%s\n",test4[1][1][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't come up with any scenario when such code would make any sense. Literally the only place in C where `char***` can perhaps be justified, is when returning a pointer-to-pointer through a function parameter. Every other use of `char***` is very likely caused by muddy or incorrect program design.

If you wish to implement a 2D array of pointers (without using structs, as would perhaps be a good idea), then the correct way would be to use a 2D array: `char* array[X][Y]`. And in case pointing at string literals, also make it `const`. Then you can point at that 2D array row by row:

Example of code that might actually make sense:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define X 2
#define Y 2

int main()
{
  const char* (*strtable) [Y] = 
    (const char* [X][Y])
    {
      { "hello",   "world" },
      { "testing", "testing" },
    };

  for(size_t i=0; i<X; i++)
  {
    for(size_t j=0; j<Y; j++)
    {
      printf("%-10s ", strtable[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```